# Hallstatt trek: Obertraun to Lodge am Krippenstein

Tags: hiking, alps, austria, solo-hiking, via-ferrata

I want to trek from Obertraun to Lodge am Krippenstein, as indicated in this google map:

https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Dachstein+Krippenstein+-+Dachstein+Tourismus+AG/Lodge+am+Krippenstein,+Winkl+52,+4831+Obertraun,+Austria/@47.5186929,13.6757139,13.54z/data=!4m14!4m13!1m5!1m1!1s0x0:0xc4f0af0d1f6f88e!2m2!1d13.705221!2d47.548288!1m5!1m1!1s0x4771371342af8ae1:0x1daa3fdb9fcb911a!2m2!1d13.6925322!2d47.5217749!3e2!5m1!1e4

I am a fit person (29 yrs old), I have alpine trekking experience, but I have no experience of ferrata and technical climbing. Is this route good for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your trail appears to follow a ski slope all the way, so you can pretty much rule out ferratas or technical climbing. Still, the snow may cover some rougher terrain in the winter (like streams that can be difficult to cross), so I'd not rely on this alone. It may not be the nicest kind of terrain to hike on, or their might be fenced-off pastures in the summer. Google Maps really isn't suited for planning an alpine trek.

I'd suggest you either get a [paper map](https://www.dav-shop.de/productdetails.aspx?id=10000036&itemno=100018) or a digital map other than Google Maps.
[This online map](https://www.outdooractive.com/en/route/hiking-trail/inneres-salzkammergut/one-day-round-tour/119800038/#dm=1) on outdooractive suggests that the upper part of the trail on Google Maps actually matches real hiking treks, but it's different at the start.

For such a "simple" hike, you might not need a map at all. I would expect there to be decent signage for the Krippenstein on signposts in Obertraun, but it's still a good idea to plan ahead.